# Handling network events on-the-fly while in background in iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voip, ios-4.2, xmppframework

Is there any way to handle network events on-the-fly in iOS 4.2.1 when app in background?

To be more specific, here are two examples:

1. Receiving VoIP call while another app in foreground
2. Receiving XMPP message while another app in foreground

Use of `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` seems not possible, since minimum delay is 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can keep a socket open when you add the `Required background modes` and add `voip` to you info.plist.
This will allow you to catch any incoming calls, the just notify the user with a `UILocalNotification`.

You can't really do it for IM system, since they do not fall in the Voip category.

Comment: When I've looked into this for a VoIP+IM client, Apple's position was "once you're voip, you're voip." That is to say that if you are in fact a VoIP client, they are not typically strict about whether you also use that ability to manage XMPP. A pure-IM client, however, needs to use push notifications to receive its messages when in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I in need for more specific reply... on iOS 4.3 my app responds when message is delivered, but on 4.2.1 - it responds only on keep-alive handler...

Comment: How do apps like Verbs accomplish this behavior?

Comment: @ChrisBallinger I don't have Verbs, but the way Facebook Messenger and WhatsApp do it by using Push notifications.